# It is any possibility to use Actuator's /info or gorylenko.git.propeties in Quarkus?

Tags: git, rest, quarkus

SpringBoot has functionality to provide deployed artifact version/commit intomation using Spring Actuator's /info or gorylenko.git.propeties.

Did we have any simillar functionality in Quarkus frm (https://quarkus.io/) ?

provide Git information on runtime for test envoirement

Comment: Since you expect answers from Quarkus users, you shouldn't assume they understand SpingBoot terminology. You should provide generic description with details on what exactly you are looking for. Also your last sentence "provide Git info...' is unclear. You are asking people to give you their time for free, so please don't be stingy with your own.

Comment: AFAIK, we don't have this, but you are welcome to request this feature on Github